# Compiling objective-c++ on Windows with clang-cl

Tags: clang, qt-creator, objective-c++, cl

I have a Qt project that was developed on MacOS. I've been given the job to make it compile on Windows.

My current problem is that compiler (Microsofts LLVM clang-cl) seems to be ignoring objective-c++ files, and the QtCreator is freaking out on `#import` statement (#import of type library is an unspported Microsoft feature). It also freaks out about a lot of stuff after that, but I'm guessing it's due to the import not being handled properly.

I was led to believe that win32-clang-mvsc was the only QtCreator compiler that supports compilation of objective-c++ files on windows, however, it doesn't seem to support the `#import` statement.

I've looked around and it seems that I would need GNUstep to be able to compile that on windows, and I'm not entirely sure it would work.

Is it possible to use the whichever compiler GNUstep provides with QtCreator? Or is there some way to use the compiler I'm already using to compile the files with `#import` statement?

The error I'm getting on the build is that ***.obj file doesn't exists, where *** is the name of the file with the `#import` statement. I'm guessing the compiler skips it and doesn't generate the .obj file, so something can't find it. I'd guess it was the linker, but I'd expect linker errors then, not a generic file not found error.

Comment: You can contact the gnustep top maintainer here at Discord, https://discord.gg/upSBRc

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GNUstep Windows MSVC Toolchain](https://github.com/gnustep/tools-windows-msvc) to build Objective-C code using Clang on Windows. We’re also using this in a Qt project. You’ll just need to tell your build system to use the necessary flags for Objective-C files (e.g. using `QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS` if you’re using QMake). This [Qt example project](https://github.com/gnustep/android-examples/tree/master/hello-objective-qt) for using Objective-C in a Qt project for Android should get you started.

The error you’re seeing about `#import` is likely because your project is using some clang-cl flags like `/TC`/`/TP` that force the compiler to treat the file as C/C++ irrespective of its extension. Removing these flags should make this error disappear.

Please open issues in the GitHub project linked above if you need further help with the setup.